# why export csv in bootstrap table is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

Please, check out my code and let me know why button export and pagination does not work? I cannot see the list of exportTypes and data-page-list.
I am using Flask to run the page. I believe that the issue is related to libraries I am using but I have no idea what to change.

Any advice from you guys would be super useful.

```js
var $table = $('#table')

$(function() {
  $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
    $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
      exportDataType: $(this).val(),
      exportTypes: ['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel', 'pdf'],
      columns: [
        {
          field: 'state',
          checkbox: true,
          visible: $(this).val() === 'selected'
        },
        {
          field: 'id',
          title: 'ID'
        }, {
          field: 'name',
          title: 'Item Name'
        }, {
          field: 'price',
          title: 'Item Price'
        }
      ]
    })
  }).trigger('change')
})
```

```css
#header_class {
      position: relative;
      background: url(../static/main_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
      margin-top: -70px;
      padding-top: 250px;
      text-align:center;
      background-attachment: relative;
      background-position: center center;
      min-height: 650px;
      width: 100%;

        -webkit-background-size: 100%;
        -moz-background-size: 100%;
        -o-background-size: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;

        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Content repository</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='logo.jpg')}}">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='PATHFINDER23_basic WO RGB.png') }}"
                                 width="150" height="25" alt="logo"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!--EXPAND MENU-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home page</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('table') }}">Table</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Log out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="header_class">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Page Content -->

<div id="toolbar" class="select">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Export Basic</option>
        <option value="all">Export All</option>
        <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
    </select>
</div>

<table id="table"
       data-show-export="true"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-side-pagination="server"
       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
       data-click-to-select="true"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-show-footer="true"
       data-url="https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data">
</table>

<!-- End Page Content -->

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.10.21/libs/jsPDF-AutoTable/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

</html>
```